# Get image URL from HTML5 canvas using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, html5-canvas

```
<canvas class="word-cloud-canvas" id="word-cloud-canvas-1892" height="270" width="320"></canvas>
```

How to get the URL source of an image from HTML5 canvas using Selenium Python?

I tried to use

```
driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].toDataURL('image/png');", canvasElement)
```

But it only return the binary? of the image.
I don't want to save the image, but get the URL of the image. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please clarify if other options (besides **selenium**) are acceptable and, if yes, review the solution provided?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and the only alternative I could find is to use `subprocess` and `phantomjs`

Here is the **Python** code

```
import json, subprocess
output = check_output(['phantomjs', 'getResources.js', main_url])
urls = json.loads(output)
for url in urls:
    #filter and process URLs
```

and the **Javascript** file content

```
// getResources.js
// Usage: 
// phantomjs getResources.js your_url

var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var urls = Array();

page.onResourceRequested = function(request, networkRequest) {
    urls.push(request.url)
};

page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(urls));
        phantom.exit();
    }, 16000);
};

page.onResourceError = function() {
    return false;
}
page.onError = function() {
    return false;
}

page.open(system.args[1]);
```

PhantomJS supports various options as well; for example to change the user agent you can use something like this:

```
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) ...';
```

This is a simplified version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27161437) which I used for my issue.